# Do both electrons in a dative bond come from the same atom?

Tags: coordination-compounds, terminology, covalent-compounds

The textbook definition of a dative bond is that it is a bond "in which the two electrons derive from the same atom" <sup>([credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_covalent_bond))</sup>.

However, I found that the two electrons of a dative bond may come from different atoms, and the two electrons of a "normal" bond may come from the same atom.

For example, consider the following reaction:

$$\ce{CH3CHBrCH3 + NaOH -> CH3CHOHCH3 + NaBr}$$

The $\ce{C-O}$ bond in $\ce{CH3CHOHCH3}$ would be an example where both electrons actually come from the $\ce{O}$ atom.

Actually, one of the electron may not have come from $\ce{O}$, but the $\ce{Na}$ atom!

What further complicates things is that all electrons are equal, so how can we tell their origins?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your textbook’s definition is inconsistent for exactly the reasons you point out. I am going to use slightly different examples than you did but they work equally well.

A prime example for dative bonding is $\ce{H3N\bond{->}BH3}$, amminborane or ‘inorganic ethane’. The latter name because it is isoelectronic to $\ce{H3C-CH3}$, (organic) ethane. Typically, amminborane is generated by ammonia reacting with $\ce{B2H6}$ — or at least it seems very plausible to create it in that way. Ethane can be created in two different ways:

1. By the recombination of two methyl radicals:
   $$\ce{H3C. + .CH3 -> H3C-CH3}\tag{1}$$
2. By the attack of a formal methide anion with a formal methanium cation:
   $$\ce{Li-CH3 + H3C-OTf -> H3C-CH3 + LiOTf}\tag{2}$$

(The second version is absolutely equivalent to your $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction to give isopropanol.)

Going by your textbook’s rules, the first reaction might generate a normal covalent bond, but the second should give a dative bond, since both electrons of the $\ce{C-C}$ bond came from methyllithium and none from methyl triflate. And, of course, we cannot distinguish between these electrons and they are delocalised all across the molecule — that goes for both ethene and amminborane.

---

A much better definition of dative versus normal covalent bonds does not consider their *generation* but rather what happens when the bond dissociation energy is added, i.e. their *dissociation.* In amminborane’s case, the dissociation happens at a rather low energy and will yield ammonia and borane again, so the electrons ‘end up where they were before.’ In more technical terms, the compound dissociates *heterolyticly.* (Equation $(3)$)

$$\ce{H3N\bond{->}BH3 -> H3N + BH3}\tag{3}$$

Ethane, on the other hand will dissociate *homolyticly* upon being fed with the (much higher) $\ce{C-C}$ bond dissociation energy. It will reform the two methyl radicals used to generate it in equation $(1)$. (Equation $(4)$)

$$\ce{H3C-CH3 -> H3C. + .CH3}\tag{4}$$

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44818/discussion-on-answer-by-jan-do-both-electrons-in-a-dative-bond-come-from-the-sam) per the request of one of the participants.